# AuthDBDUserPWQuery with multiply tables

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication, sql, svn

I have a MySQL authentication for SVN server. Configuration file looks like this:

```
<Location /svn/project>
    ...
    AuthDBDUserPWQuery "SELECT Password FROM SVNUsers WHERE Nickname = %s"
    ...
</Location>
```

It works perfectly. But, there is a need appeared to fetch users from second table. At first, I tried to use UNION (of-course!). Like this:

```
    AuthDBDUserPWQuery "SELECT Password FROM SVNUsers WHERE Nickname = %s UNION SELECT Password FROM Users WHERE Nickname = %s"
```

But, it doesn't work because I have two %s statements, and second one doesn't get replaced with a nickname. Then I tried to declare a SQL variable, write %s to it and use it. Like this:

```
    AuthDBDUserPWQuery "SET @userName = %s; SELECT Password FROM SVNUsers WHERE Nickname = @userName"
```

But, AuthDBDUserPWQuery doesn't understand variables. How to solve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use MySQL Functions:

```
AuthDBDUserPWQuery "SELECT SVNAuthenticationFunction(%s) as Password"
```